# Storing text file data in variable

Tags: c#

Is it possible to store a text file data in a variable knowing only its extension?I was thinking something like

```
string path = @"D:\MyTest";
 var txt = File.ReadAllLines(path + "*.txt");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to look for files with `.txt` extension and if any of them has been found, load the content:

```
  string path = @"D:\MyTest";

  // Please, notice that you'll have an array string[] txt
  // If you want just String txt output (not array) change ReadAllLines to ReadAllText  
  var txt = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt")
      // If you can have many text files you may want to add a filter here:
      // .Where(file => ...)
    .Select(file => File.ReadAllLines(file))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't have an extension in the file name. No need to specify the extension.

```
string path = @"D:\MyTest";
var txt = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```